# Writing CSV from scraped HTML data

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I was able to extract data using below code from the Russian Statistics website and to create a CSV file. However, I have two issues, firstly, I don't know why there is always a blank row inserted between two-non-blank rows. Secondly, I am unaware how to write a nice table where data from the same month is spread across different columns. Right now, everything is just in one cell. Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import urllib2
import csv

f=csv.writer(open("Russia.csv","w"))
mainurl='http://www.gks.ru/bgd/free/B00_25/IssWWW.exe/Stg/d000/I000750R.HTM'
urlroot='http://www.gks.ru/bgd/free/B00_25/IssWWW.exe/Stg/d000/'

data = urllib2.urlopen(mainurl).read()
page = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

for link in page.findAll('a'):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(urlroot+link.get('href'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    years=soup.findAll('title',text=True)

    table = soup.find('center').find('table')
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[3:]:
        cells = [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all('td')]
        f.writerow([cells])
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @alecxe; my desired output looks like this [example for row 1 in the csv]: January; 112,8; 28,2; 1,2 [then the next item on the next row, and so on for all items in my list], so a csv which lists each item's data in my list on each row. Right now, my problem is that the csv writer literally writes unicode " u' " before each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unintentionally making *a list of lists* here:

```
cells = [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all('td')]
f.writerow([cells])
```

Instead, write the `cells` list directly:

```
f.writerow(cells)
```